# Case expression in BizTalk Expression Shape

Tags: expression, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009, biztalk-orchestrations

How to write the CASE statement in expression shape in BizTalk Orchestration?

I have tried by using below code but, it is saying "identifier case does not exist in unnamed are you missing an assembly reference?"

```
switch case <value>
{
   case "1":
       construct message1
       {
             message1=message2;
        }
       break;
   case default:
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The BizTalk orchestration expression editor has a [variety of limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559103.aspx), most notably that a lot of C# code you would normally write elsewhere is not accepted: the `switch` statement being one example.

As long as you use a normal expression shape (i.e., not a message assignment shape), you can use IF-ELSE statements (minus assignment within the if predicate). The stated reason Microsoft only allows a subset of C# is [“to keep code for the business process separate from its implementation code.”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559103.aspx)

So if you want to do complex message assignment, you should not pack it into a single expression shape (Microsoft tries hard to stop you). You can instead use a [Decide shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560761.aspx) as equivalent to your case, with each branch taking you to the appropriate message assignment/expression.

If you need more than just a few possible branches, then you can consider writing a C# helper assembly with all of your message assignment logic in order to avoid an overly complex orchestration.

Answer (score 1):

`switch`, among other things, is not supported in an Expression Shape.

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559103.aspx

The Orchestration equivalent is typically the Decide Shape.